# PHP function is storing random values into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have been looking the solution for long time that why does my added fields are not stored in database properly and concluded that jquery is not adding html field properly that is why it is not submitted to render php program to add the fields data in database.

for proper demonstration please have a look at the code

My HTML form code is written as

```
<table id="additional_item_numbers">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>&nbsp;Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-inps" size="50" name="additional_item_numbers[]" value="123" /></td><td>
<a class="delete_item_number" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and jquery function is defined to add a new field in form on **ENTER** key press

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$("#additional_item_numbers").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#additional_item_numbers tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-inps" size="40" name="additional_item_numbers[]" value="" /></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
            //document.getElementById("form-inps").focus();
            $("#additional_item_numbers").find("input[type='text']").last().focus();
    }
});
</script>
```

***This function perfectly add a new field in the html form but upon submission of this form the fields are added into database randomly.
sometimes not a single value is added to database and some time random values are added and some time all values are added upon submission.***
If I check the **source code** of the page after adding new fields with jquery function. it does not show those newly added fields in source code.
**I think it is due to client side functionality** but it should add all the values to database after submission. but it does not. and if I go to edit an item and add some further additional item numbers then the same `save()` function of php is called and it does not miss a single value of the submitted form from previous item numbers but the additional added item numbers behave same as described above.

**After searching a lot and diving deep in php code, I think that jquery is not setting the name of newly added fields properly, so those fields data whose name is set up properly is submitted to php function and it stores that data into database but those whose name was not set properly does not go to php program so they don't appear in database.**

For better understanding, I am including the php function code too.

My PHP function to add data into database.

```
function save($item_id, $additional_item_numbers)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->delete('additional_item_numbers', array('item_id' => $item_id));

        foreach($additional_item_numbers as $item_number)
        {
            if ($item_number!='')
            {
                $this->db->insert('additional_item_numbers', array('item_id' => $item_id, 'item_number' => $item_number));
            }
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete();

        return TRUE;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time I got the root point of the problem, It was a database error because database table was defined not to store a duplicate value and each time, I was placing a duplicate value, it was not stored in the database, this was the cause of random behavior of the program. when I providing unique values, It was updating the database properly and whenever there was a duplicate in the values, then after duplication value, it was not storing further values into database. To get it work, just change the structure of your database or

**in my case:** My requirement was, no duplication but all the values besides the duplicate values should be stored in the database and I achieved this by changing

```
$this->db->insert('additional_item_numbers', array('item_id' => $item_id, 'item_number' => $item_number));
```

to

```
$this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO additional_item_numbers (item_id, item_number) VALUES ('".$item_id."', '".$item_number."')");
```

Thanks all for your answers. Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google Chrome?  Hit F12 to pull up the developer tools.  You can inspect what the JavaScript is adding to the page.

Internet Explorer and Firefox can also pull up developer tools by hitting F12.

I would recommend not using [] in the value of the name attribute, because it is a little confusing.  Some people might think this is an array or the value of an array instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir and I am using firefox and I want to assign these values to an array, that is why I am using `[]` with the name... an item could have more than 150 item numbers. e.g If item is SIM card there could be 100s of sim numbers so I need all those values in an array and want to add all of those to database. I checked developer tools by F12, it shows the same name which is added in jquery i.e `name="additional_item_numbers[]"` not sure why it is doing this then.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to this but I would imagine you could use a Debugger and Element Inspection to look at your javascript and html elements.  The concept is the same between browsers.

Chrome:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the Basics:

I do not see a `<form action="script.php">`

In FireFox before you submit the form.  Right click anywhere on page and select "Inspect Element"

In the FireFox Inspector window, Go to the "Network" tab and click the "Reload" button

submit the form

In the FireFox Inspector window, click on the page in the file column

Select "Params" in box that appears when the page is selected. (usually to right side)

The submitted data should be listed.

It will look like this in key:value format:

```
additional_item_numbers[]:"value submitted is here"
```

the key (field name) in blue and the value in orange

Answer (score 0):

Where is additional_item_numbers defined?  If you want to use it like a variable, you need to change this line to:

```
$("#additional_item_numbers tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-inps" size="40" name="' + additional_item_numbers[0] + '" value="" /></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but no, that is not the case. I want all those entries in php array that is why I am including `[]` in name attribute. so when I will get the values of these inputs, I will use `$_POST['additional_item_numbers']` in php and it will return all the entered values in an array form. The main issue is, it is behaving randomly. sometime it stores all values. some times it stores nothing and some times it stores random values of input text boxes.